# Tkinter scrolling (scrollbar on frames)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am still new to this and I need some help in inserting a scrollbar to scroll the circled area just in case the list gets long in future. Thanks in advance.
[The image is included here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxvE1.png)(the circled area is actually an individual frame so is there any method to add scrollbar to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to create a [canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) with [scrollbars](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm) and then place the frame which contains the checkbox widgets on the canvas with [create_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method).